# Searching another WP7 device in same network

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking

I am working on a application in WP7 in which if the application is running on one WP7 device, it should search for another WP7 device having the same application installed in close proximity, or lets say if they are in the same network.

How it can be done ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions to this problem. Either build a backend service which saves the location of the users, and use this data to show if a user is nearby. This would then not require the users to be on the same network, but requires you to have backend service. (And store user location data, which not all users are comfortable with).

The other solution, which might be better in your case is to use broadcasting in a UDP Unicast group. This would limit it to users on the same network though. There is a nice tutorial of this [over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286407%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot.. I am not sure which of the two solutions i am going to use. But they both will do the work. Thanks again..